# Cannot pip install via proxy when on Conda env

Tags: python, proxy, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have some weird problem with pip install via proxy.

When I'm in the base Conda environment (`/conda`) pip install works fine (using proxy: `HTTPS_PROXY` env variable).

But when I'm switching to another Conda environment, I get proxy errors:

```
$ conda activate /User/bryan_env
$ pip install xmltodict 
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/xmltodict/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/xmltodict/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/xmltodict/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/xmltodict/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/xmltodict/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xmltodict
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xmltodict
```

I've tried to use `.condarc` as well but had the same errors.

Important to say that this is all in Jupyter shell running in Kuberenetes pod.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was solved by reinstalling pip **in** the environment using:

```
conda install -c anaconda pip
```

After that, try your pip install. It worked for me.